# Android Studio 2.3 doesn't have Test Instrumentation specifier in UI

Tags: android, testing, automation, automated-tests, android-espresso

After updating to Android Studio 2.3 when I try to run some espresso tests I get the following error:

> Test running failed: Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{com.example.android/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner}
>   Empty test suite.

This was easily fixable in the past where in the Run Configuration I could specify my own `InstrumentationRunner`. Now I can't seem to find this option so I can't really specify my runner class now.

Note that my build gradle does contain

```
defaultConfig {
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    resConfigs "en", "es"
}
```

Comment: I've moved to just running connected tests from the terminal until I can figure out how to get them working on the IDE again.

Comment: Did the same, but I was looking for a more conveninent solution ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41425067/how-to-add-extra-test-runner-parameter-in-android-studio-2-3-instrumented-tests and there is an issue for that on tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37132226

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem this morning. I deleted the old run configuration (the one that was created before you specified the new runner via `build.gradle`). I re-ran the tests and the new runner was picked up by Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

On Android Studio 2.3 this feature is not available as this was an optional to specify the Instrumentation Runner package/class in previous versions of Studio. But Android 2.3 is smart enough to pick this from your build.gradle file provided you have defined Instrumentation package runner there.

Comment: Aparently it's not smart enough or I am doing something wrong. Because it doesn't pick it up from my `build.gradle`

Comment: Define package runner in your build.gradle file present under 'project' folder like this :   defaultConfig { def testRunnerPackage = "com.app.test.espresso.InstrumentationTestRunner" } Here make sure you enter correct package name.

Answer (score 0):

The following setup fixed the issue

```
productFlavors {
        doTheTests {
            minSdkVersion 18
            testInstrumentationRunner "com.company.app.test.TestRunner"
            if (System.getenv('CONTINUOUS_INTEGRATION').equals("true")) {
                testInstrumentationRunnerArguments(package: "com.company.app.test")
            }
        }
    }
```

Because Android Studio doesn't allow the `testInstrumentationRunnerArguments` but executing the tests through terminal indeed requires it!

Obviously on the terminal / CI system, set an environment variable like:
`export CONTINUOUS_INTEGRATION=true`

Comment: I tried your solution but I get the following error `Error:(282, 0) ProductFlavor names cannot start with 'test'`

Comment: @AdrianOlar change the name please! Edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

What helped to me - starting the test from command line then syncing the project.